# Relation between linear momentum and translational kinetic energy

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, lagrangian-formalism, momentum

The momentum $m v$ of a particle is formally the same as the **derivative** its translational kinetic energy $\frac{1}{2} m v^2$ with respect to $v$.

Similarly the angular momentum $I \omega$ is the **derivative** of its rotational energy $\frac{1}{2}I \omega^2$ with respect to $\omega$.

Does this relation has any physical interpretation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed, in Hamiltonian Formalism this is the very definition of momentum. For example, for a free particle with one generalised coordinate $q$ and $\dot{q}\equiv v$ the Lagrangian is

$$ L=\frac{1}{2}mv^2 $$

and the momentum is (by definition) given by

$$ p =\frac{\partial L}{\partial v}$$

Check any book in classical mechanics for Lagrangian and Hamiltonian formalism for more details in the subject.